# How to find and avoid uninitialised primitive members in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, static-analysis

There is a common C++ bug with uninitialised primitive members:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:    
    int x;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  std::cout << a.x;
  return 0; 
}
```

`a.x` will be uninitialised. I understand why it happens and want to find a solution for catching such bugs. I checked gcc and cppcheck, they don't report these members.

**EDIT**
Checked gcc with flags `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -Wold-style-cast -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wunreachable-code`

The first version of gcc that detects a bug is 5.1. g++-4.9 doesn't detect it, clang++-3.6 fails too.

Comment: The problem seems contrived to me. A constructor should establish the class's invariants; if you don't do that, no magic can help you.

Comment: @KerrekSB: In terms of program design and all that jazz, absolutely. But it's nice to have diagnostics when you fail to do so, no?

Comment: @KerrekSB it's a simplified example. If you have 500 classes with 0-5 members each, you make same mistake eventually.

Comment: Since C++11 you might change your coding style and initialize in  the member declaration `int x = 0`.  This makes it easy to see uninitialized values.

Comment: @KerrekSB Do you compile with all warnings off because the code *should* be correct? I don't understand your objection.

Comment: @Barry: I don't follow -- of course I compile with all warnings *on* so my compiler tells me when my code isn't correct. So I don't need a language feature to deal with this "problem".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Of course -- and thankfully you do have those diagnostics :-)

Comment: @DieterLücking: Arguably it makes it _harder_ to see when you've not set the values to what you actually wanted them to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes they do](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ee30ff73da93de9)… sort of:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:18: warning: 'a.A::x' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   std::cout << a.x;
                  ^
0
```

In the above linked example, I'm using GCC 5.1 trunk with `-Wall`.

**Turn on more GCC warnings and/or upgrade.**

Also tested, and found *not* to warn:

- GCC 4.4.7
- GCC 4.9.2 (by [RiaD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768110/riad))
- Clang 3.6.0

Honestly I'm not sure what else you can do. You could create a tool to do this, but then you'd be creating a compiler or static analyser. :)

So, I guess, just hope the people who know how to do that catch up…

Comment: Interestingly, Clang doesn't warn here even with -Wall -Wextra -Wuninitialized

Comment: Just waiting for Ira to show up promoting his static analysis product :P

Comment: The traditional C answer was a separate strict checking tool, _lint_, because with the machines available at the timestrict checking slowed the compiler down too much to do every time. C++ compilers inherited that default. But with today's hardware, starting with -Wall is a cheap investment in better code!

Answer (score 1):

This bug is diagnosed by `valgrind` with the (default) tool `memcheck`, producing a number of warnings, including:

```
$ valgrind ./unin
…
==12185== Use of uninitialised value of size 8 
==12185==    at 0x4F39BC3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==12185==    by 0x4F3AD89: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==12185==    by 0x4F3AF8C: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==12185==    by 0x4F474E9: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)             
==12185==    by 0x400763: main (in [censored]/unin)
```

It should also be found by Clang's address sanitizer. However, I realize you are most interested in a compile-time check. After all, the existing test suites may never execute some of the code, and catching a bug sooner is always better. You could use GCC 5.1 (even if you used it *only* for this purpose), or you could use a dedicated static analyzer. Fortunately, clang comes with a static analyzer invoked as `scan-build` (included in at least the Debian/Ubuntu packages):

```
$ scan-build clang -c unin.cxx 
scan-build: Using '/usr/lib/llvm-3.6/bin/clang' for static analysis
unin.cxx:10:3: warning: Function call argument is an uninitialized value
  std::cout << a.x;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
scan-build: 1 bug found.
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I'm already using g++-5.1, but it fails to detect tricky cases. Will try clang next week